# Report Designer Validation Failed on Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have published from the metadata editor. I am trying to publish from Report Designer. It is allowing me to publish, but once the website opens it says that the report validation failed. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the Pentaho Logs (pentaho/server/biserver-ee/logs) and try to check what the log is recording when you are trying to launch it. Assuming you are using the userconsole to view the report.

Comment: Do you use a ktr for the report? and Is it a Linux machine that you use? I encountered the same issue and fixed it. I can answer if you answer my two questions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I used different versions of Pentaho. Try matching the same versions for Pentaho Report Designer and Pentaho BA Server.